# How to get all boards in jira project using either Rest API or jira-ruby gem

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to use this [How to get all sprints in project using JIRA REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821683/how-to-get-all-sprints-in-project-using-jira-rest-api) to build code which gets all sprints for jira project. I miss one piece however: **how to get all boards in jira project**?

Proposed solution is to

1. use https://myjira.com/rest/agile/1.0/board to get all boards
2. and for every board to query https://myjira.com/rest/agile/1.0/board/BOARD_ID/project to find out if it belongs to my project.

However my jira has ~10'000 boards. I can't make 10'000 JIRA queries for them. I need something like https://myjira.com/rest/agile/1.0/board?project=PROJECTNAME. If that's not possible, then I need at least to include project name into /board result.

Answer (score 0):

Acc. to https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/7.3.1/?#agile/1.0/board-getAllBoards you can use the `projectKeyOrId` parameter in your GET request to provide the project's key, e.g.

```
https://myjira.com/rest/agile/1.0/board?projectKeyOrId=PROJECTNAME
```