# Get the sprint list with start and end dates

Tags: jira, jira-agile, jira-rest-java-api

I am looking for a rest API to get all the sprints with their respective start and end dates. I can get the list of sprints using the API

```
rest/greenhopper/1.0/sprintquery/boardId?includeFutureSprints=true&includeHistoricSprints=false
```

and the sprint information using

```
rest/agile/1.0/sprint/sprintId
```

However, it will require me to get call the 2nd API for each sprint. Is there an API that provide the list of sprints along with their information such as start and end date.

Comment: within `bash`, you can get it using this script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378905/1499296

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on JIRA 7 using JIRA Software, you can use:
[GET /rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardId}/sprint](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/cloud/#agile/1.0/board/%7BboardId%7D/sprint-getAllSprints)

This will return results that include *startDate* and *endDate*, e.g.:

```
{
    "maxResults": 2,
    "startAt": 1,
    "total": 5,
    "isLast": false,
    "values": [{
        "id": 37,
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/agile/1.0/sprint/23",
        "state": "closed",
        "name": "sprint 1",
        "startDate": "2015-04-11T15:22:00.000+10:00",
        "endDate": "2015-04-20T01:22:00.000+10:00",
        "completeDate": "2015-04-20T11:04:00.000+10:00",
        "originBoardId": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 72,
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/agile/1.0/sprint/73",
        "state": "future",
        "name": "sprint 2"
    }]
}
```